# Unexpected DWDS error for callServiceExtension: WipError -32000 Execution context was destroyed

Tags: flutter, zegocloud

I am using zegocloud for chat app and running on  web.When i run on web it gives error as:
**ext.flutter.connectedVmServiceUri: (-32603) Unexpected DWDS error for callServiceExtension: WipError -32000 Execution context was destroyed.
Failed to set vm service URI: ext.flutter.connectedVmServiceUri: (-32603) Unexpected DWDS error for callServiceExtension: WipError -32000 Execution context was destroyed.. Deep links to DevTools will not show in Flutter errors.
Failed to set DevTools server address: ext.flutter.activeDevToolsServerAddress: (-32603) Unexpected DWDS error for callServiceExtension: WipError -32000 Execution context was destroyed.. Deep links to DevTools will not show in Flutter errors.**

**main.dart**

```
void main() {
  ZIMKit().init(
    appSecret: constants().secret,

    notificationConfig: ZegoZIMKitNotificationConfig(
        resourceID: "1",
        supportOfflineMessage: true,
        androidNotificationConfig: ZegoZIMKitAndroidNotificationConfig(
            channelID: "1",
            channelName: "messaging",
            
            icon: AutofillHints.birthday,
            sound: AutofillHints.birthday),
        iosNotificationConfig: ZegoZIMKitIOSNotificationConfig(
          certificateIndex: ZegoSignalingPluginMultiCertificate.firstCertificate,
          isSandboxEnvironment: true,
        )),
    appID: constants().APPID, // your appid
    appSign: constants().APPSIGN, // your appSign
  );

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

**log on terminal**

**plugin type:ZegoUIKitPluginType.signaling install (149644980)
[INFO] 2024-01-18 08:14:16.699 [signaling] [notification] enable Notify When App Running In Background Or Quit, is iOS Sandbox Environment:true, enable iOS VoIP:false, certificate index:ZegoSignalingPluginMultiCertificate.firstCertificate, appName: , androidChannelID: 1, androidChannelName: messaging, androidSound: /raw/birthday
[INFO] 2024-01-18 08:14:16.702 [adapter] [system service] init system service
[ZIMKit] init offline message, config:resource id:1, suppor…SignalingPluginMultiCertificate.firstCertificate**